# Scalar Multiplication

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

**EDIT**
The question is this: Scalar multiplication is defined as B = A * s, where B and A are equally sized matrices (2D array of numbers, in this example let's use integers) and s is a scalar value. Each element of A is multiplied to s, which is then stored in the corresponding element in matrix B.

Write a program that accepts a 4x4 matrix and a scalar value, and perform scalar multiplication, storing the result in a separate 4x4 matrix.

```
import java.util.*;
public class arrayExercises {

public static void main (String [] args){

//Scalar Value  
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int scalar = 0;

//Array for A
int matrix [][];
matrix = new int [4][4];

System.out.println("Enter the numbers in the 4x4 matrix");
for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
    for (int j =0; j<matrix[i].length; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();    
}

System.out.println("Enter scaler value:");
scalar = sc.nextInt();



sc.close(); 
}
```

}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi. People will be more willing to help you out if you show that you have tried something. Do you have a partial solution that didn't work?

Comment: The question is this: Scalar multiplication is defined as B = A * s, where B and A are equally sized matrices (2D array of numbers, in this example let's use integers) and s is a scalar value. Each element of A is multiplied to s, which is then stored in the corresponding element in matrix B. 

Write a program that accepts a 4x4 matrix and a scalar value, and perform scalar multiplication, storing the result in a separate 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

not giving a direct solution. giving you a hint instead.

so far from your code, you have created a matrix and withing 2 for loop you have set the values of the matrix from user input.

now to get a scalar multiplication you need to do a similar operation. create another matrix of the same size as the previous matrix. and in a similar way within 2 loop multiply each and every element of the old matrix with the scalar value and set it to the coresponding index of the new matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter scaler value:");
scalar = sc.nextInt();

int scalarMatrix [][];
scalarMatrix = new int [4][4];

for (int i=0; i < scalarMatrix.length; i++)
    {
    for (int j =0; j<scalarMatrix[i].length; j++)
        scalarMatrix[i][j] = (int)(matrix[i][j]*scalar);    
}
```

Something along these lines should work. What you are doing is getting each result from the initial matrix and essentially copying them into the new matrix but multiplying it by the variable "scalar" as you do so.